# How do I move something in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a programming noob, and learning Rails. I'm making a GTD webapp for fun, and I'd like  to make a "done" section. In other words, I have a link that says "Done!" and I want that to move the current task into a done page, instead of index.html.erb. All I know about Rails is what was in the official beginner tutorial.

Comment: This is pretty high level. I would suggest breaking down you question into multiple parts and also include some code samples. What is GTD? Getting Things Done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set a property like 'completed' on a task. There are a lot of things that have to happen for this to work

Your task model needs to have a property like 'completed' 
Your controller needs to have an action to mark as completed (you can possibly just use the standard 'update' action..)
You need to have a route to that action
Your view needs to call that action